# System Dependence Graph tree

Tags: java, graph, tree, static-analysis

on the internet there is a lot of exemple of sdg that gives a tree with dependencies but i didn't know how to get it 
how to get tree from SDG program ? , i tried with  `printAll` but it doesn't give me tree
i used

```
 SystemDependenceGraph lvSystemDependenceGraph=new SystemDependenceGraph(pathDirectory,pathClassName,methodeName);
```

amd i imported SDG.jar

Comment: You've given us no details on what you're using. What library are you using to generate this tree?

Comment: SystemDependenceGraph lvSystemDependenceGraph=new SystemDependenceGraph(pathDirectory,pathClassName,methodeName); and i importet SDG.jar

Comment: To add information, please do not use the comments. Edit your question using the **edit** button, and add everything there. If code is involved, make sure you format it (inline using backticks, in its own block using the `{}` button).

Comment: i edited my post do you have an answer please !?